# resource ordering synchronization issue "->" doesn't work?

Tags: puppet

I have encounter really weird behaviour which goes against what I have learned, tutorial says etc. So I would be glad if someone could explain why that is happening.
I have a role module which is made up of composition of profiles (role-profile pattern). My role consists:

```
   class role::lab_prg_c2_dn inherits lab_prg_c2 {
    class { 'profile::cluster_data_node':
      namenode_fqdn          => $role::lab_prg_c2::namenode_fqdn,
      secondarynamenode_fqdn => $role::lab_prg_c2::secondarynamenode_fqdn,          
  } 
  ->
  class{'bigdatasolution':}
}
```

First class installs technology and second one installs our components and items which are build on top of technology. Hence the technology need to be installed first, thats the reason for "->" dependency. However this seems to me doesn't work correctly. As components from class 'bigdatasolution' are installed somewhere before the class profile::cluster_data_node finishes. 
I tried to use require => Class['profile::cluster_data_node'] but that doesn't make any difference! 
The content of class{'bigdatasolution':} :

```
   class bigdatasolution {
  $hdfs_default_conf  = '/usr/local/hadoop.hdfs.conf'
  $hbase_default_conf = '/usr/local/hadoop.hbase.conf'

  include symlinks
  include bdjar
}
```

Symlinks - create symlinks for the configuration installed in class profile::cluster_data_node and are not directly managed - it will be presented when actually specified package get installed.

bdjar - add our jar to a technology library so content is as follows:

```
class bigdatasolution::bdjar {
  file { "/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/bigdata-properties.jar":
    ensure => present,
    mode   => 0644,
    group  => 'root',
    owner  => 'root',
    source => "puppet:///modules/bigdatasolution/bigdata-properties.jar"
  }
}
```

I even tried to put require => "technologycalClass" here but that doesn't help either.

Can someone please help me understand what's wrong and how that should be solved properly?
I Using puppet 3 and ordering is specified explicetly - so no arbitrary ordering set by puppet should happen.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with *As components from class bigdatasolution are installed somewhere before the class profile::cluster_data_node finishes.* Your code should install 'bigdatasolution' AFTER 'profile::cluster_data_node', and AFTER all resources **required** and **included** in it, but NOT after  resources **notified** by 'profile::cluster_data_node'

Comment: Yea, that is the intent that 'bigdatasolution' should be synchronized after 'profile::cluster_data_node' and its content but that isn't what is currently happening. There is no explicit notification defined. That's why I am posting that here as I do not understand why the behaviour is not as I expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your 'profile::cluster_data_node' class 'includes' other classes/modules they will have no dependency ordering with the 'bigdatasolution' class.

I see you actually do include symlinks and bdjar. Basically every piece of ordering you want to have in puppet, you need to write explicitly.

Here you should replace the include statements with require, that way the class cluster_data_node will require the other two modules to complete before it says it has completed. Include is a pretty lose way of importing things in puppet and in my opinion is best to just avoid it and go with explicit require statements instead.

TL;DR: included modules have no transitive ordering; required modules do.

Comment: There is nothing like containment? E.g. Class bigdata includes bdjar and symlinks. As I want to synchronize those latter I set on bigdata required on module which I want to happen first. That module my include (contain) other resources. If that really doesn't work what is a best approach to avoid inter module dependency deep inside the modules as I see that a potential problem for maintenace.

Comment: In my experience the best way to avoid it in the future is to never use includes. Always keep in mind that the way puppet applies resources is by mapping them together as a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG), so you should have a decent mental model (you can output the actual graph too) of how your model interacts with other ones. Definitely not ideal, but the alternative is to use the anchor pattern. EDIT: Puppet documents this stuff [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_containment.html)